# Centering a circular smartdiagram

Tags: smartdiagram

[image: Here is what the diagram looks like and my notes about the desired changes in red]I have this circular smartdiagram. I am asking for help to center one of the modules at the top and have the remaining three at each side. Here's what I have:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions} 
\begin{document}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\smartdiagramconnect}{m m}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \foreach \start/\end in {#2}
  \draw[additional item arrow type,#1]
  (\start) to (\end);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
    \centering
\smartdiagramset{uniform color list=teal!60 for 7 items,
                    back arrow distance=0.75,
                    sequence item border color=black,
                    uniform arrow color=true,
                    arrow color=gray!50!black,
                    circular distance=6cm,
                    font=\normalsize,
                    text width=3.5cm,
                    module minimum width=3.5cm,
                    module minimum height=2.0cm,
                    arrow line width=2.5pt,
                    arrow tip=to,
                 additions={
                additional arrow style=dashed,
                additional arrow color=black,   
                additional arrow line width=2pt,
                          }
                    } 
\smartdiagramadd[circular diagram:clockwise]{
     Step 1: Define the Construct,Step 2: Determine Facets and Generate Narrative \mbox{Descriptions} for Each Facet,Step 3: Determine the Facet Levels and Generate Descriptions to Capture Variation within Each Facet, Step 4: \mbox{Determine} the Structure of the Scenarios,Step 5: \mbox{Developing} the Mapping \mbox{Sentences} and \mbox{Constructing} the Scenarios,Step 6: Decide on the Response Options and Survey Instructions, Step 7: Testing Congruence of \mbox{Theory} and Practice
    }
    {}
    \smartdiagramconnect{->, shorten <=8pt, shorten >=8pt, bend left=30,}{module2/module1}
      \smartdiagramconnect{->, shorten <=8pt, shorten >=8pt, bend left=30,}{module7/module6, module6/module5, module5/module4}

\end{document}
```

[image: I tried changing the text order but even if I put Step 1 text on the box of Step 2 it isn't centered at 12 o'clock]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Your code is not compilable.

Comment: Hi, I was able to compile the edit above.

Comment: With which engine? pdfLaTex? LaTeX? another one?

Comment: I compiled in overleaf

Comment: @mariabc were you able to accept the answer to your previous question regarding smartdiagram

Comment: @mariabc could you include a hand sketch of the desired output

Comment: Indeed, on overleaf your code compiles. But not on MikTeX where the `figure` environment is incompatible with the standalone class. Removing the `figure` environment will cause it to compile on MikTeX.

Comment: @jsbibra I accepted your answer on my previous post, thnx. I've added a visual to this post with my notes about what I'd like to change.

Comment: The positioning of the modules is hard-coded in the package, if your request is imperative, you must ask its maintainer to add this possibility to its package or use another tool *(such as TikZ for example)* to do the same thing. You will find his email address in the manual, here: [CTAN smartdiagram](https://ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The positioning of the modules is hard-coded in the `smartdiagram` package, if your request is imperative, you must ask its maintainer to add this possibility to its package. You will find his email address in the manual.

Here is a version coded with the TikZ `chain` library. It is **parameterized** and allows you to display any regular polygons as for example with as **many sides** as you want. You can also choose **where to position module 1** and the **inner radius** of the polygon.

*p.s: Personally, I am not convinced that placing the module 1 to 12 hours is more aesthetic than what is natively done by the `smartdiagram` package.*

## Update: add internal dashed arrows

In this example, I called the whole polygon chain `(polygon)`. The first node is called `(polygon-1)`; the second node is called `(polygon-2)`, and so on. This corresponds to the **modules** of smartdiagram.
To draw arrows, we use the classic TikZ code. And since it is a node (i.e. a box full of text), we can tell where the arrows should start and end by using the syntax `(polygon-1.east)` or `(polygon-1.90)`. This is called an anchor.

The curvature of the arrows is determined by the parameter `bend left=40`, I put different curvatures *(`bend left=30` and `bend left=10`)* so that you can see this curvature.

I quote the manual where the node is called `(s)`, then you see `(s.10)`; `(s.east)`, etc.

> **Shape rectangle**
> This shape, which is the standard, is a rectangle around the text. The inner
> and outer separations (see Section 17.2.3) influence the white space around the > text. The following figure shows the anchors this shape defines; the anchors **10** > and **130** are example of border anchors.

[image: screenshot]

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {chains}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\def\nbcote{7}% number of side
\def\startmodule{90}% position of module 1
\def\rayon{6.5cm}%<- radius of polygon
\definecolor{teal}{RGB}{0,128,128}

\tikzset{every node/.style={on chain,text width=3.5cm,draw,rounded corners,minimum width=3.5cm,minimum height=2.8cm,top color=white,bottom color=teal!60
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain= polygon placed {at=({\startmodule+(\tikzchaincount-1)*(-360/\nbcote)}:\rayon)}]
\foreach \texte [count=\i from 1]in 
  {Step 1: Define the Construct,Step 2: Determine Facets and Generate Narrative \mbox{Descriptions} for Each Facet,Step 3: Determine the Facet Levels and Generate Descriptions to Capture Variation within Each Facet, Step 4: \mbox{Determine} the Structure of the Scenarios,Step 5: \mbox{Developing} the Mapping \mbox{Sentences} and \mbox{Constructing} the Scenarios,Step 6: Decide on the Response Options and Survey Instructions, Step 7: Testing Congruence of \mbox{Theory} and Practice}
    {\node [] {\texte};
    }

%\draw (0,0) circle (\rayon);% <- circle inscribed in the polygon

\foreach \i [evaluate={
            \next=int(1+mod({\i},\nbcote));}] 
        in {1,...,\nbcote}{
\draw[->,line width=2pt] (polygon-\i)to[bend left=10](polygon-\next);
}
\draw [->,line width=2pt,dashed] (polygon-7) to [bend left=10] (polygon-6);
\draw [->,line width=2pt,dashed] (polygon-6.east) to [bend left=30] (polygon-5.60);
\draw [->,line width=2pt,dashed] (polygon-5.40) to [bend left=40] (polygon-4.130);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## First answer:

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {chains}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\def\nbcote{7}% number of side
\def\startmodule{90}% position of module 1
\def\rayon{6.5cm}%<- radius of polygon
\definecolor{teal}{RGB}{0,128,128}

\tikzset{every node/.style={on chain,text width=3.5cm,draw,rounded corners,minimum width=3.5cm,minimum height=2.8cm,top color=white,bottom color=teal!60
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain= polygon placed {at=({\startmodule+(\tikzchaincount-1)*(-360/\nbcote)}:\rayon)}]
\foreach \texte [count=\i from 1]in 
  {Step 1: Define the Construct,Step 2: Determine Facets and Generate Narrative \mbox{Descriptions} for Each Facet,Step 3: Determine the Facet Levels and Generate Descriptions to Capture Variation within Each Facet, Step 4: \mbox{Determine} the Structure of the Scenarios,Step 5: \mbox{Developing} the Mapping \mbox{Sentences} and \mbox{Constructing} the Scenarios,Step 6: Decide on the Response Options and Survey Instructions, Step 7: Testing Congruence of \mbox{Theory} and Practice}
    {\node [] {\texte};
    }

%\draw (0,0) circle (\rayon);% <- circle inscribed in the polygon

\foreach \i [evaluate={
            \next=int(1+mod({\i},\nbcote));}] 
        in {1,...,\nbcote}{
\draw[->,line width=2pt] (polygon-\i)to[bend left=10](polygon-\next);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I add the internal dashed lines with tikz?

Comment: Here it is, I added explanations. Is it clear now?

Comment: how would I center the text in the nodes?

Comment: @FrederickNord like this `{\node [align=center] {\texte};}`

Answer (score 1):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

The nodes are defined in the key `slices`. The macro `\WCcount` gives the current number of the slice.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[
  data=,
  radius={5}{5},
  slices={;\node[
    bottom color=teal!60,
    top color=teal!10,
    rounded corners,
    draw=gray,
    align=center,
    minimum width=3.5cm,
    minimum height=2.0cm
  ] (WCslice\WCcount) {Step \WCcount: \WCvarA};},
  slices style={},
  start half,
  value=1
]{%
  Define\\the Construct,
  Determine\\Facets and Generate\\Narrative Descriptions\\for Each Facet,
  Determine\\the Facet Levels and\\Generate Descriptions\\to Capture Variation\\within Each Facet,
  Determine\\the Structure of\\the Scenarios,
  Developing\\the Mapping\\Sentences and\\Constructing\\the Scenarios,
  Decide on the\\Response Options and\\Survey Instructions,
  Testing\\Congruence of\\Theory and Practice%
}
\foreach\n in {1,...,7}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{int(Mod(\n,7)+1)}
  \draw[->,line width=2pt] (WCslice\n) to[bend left=10] (WCslice\k);
}
\foreach\n in {2,5,6,7}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{int(Mod(\n-2,7)+1)}
  \draw[->,line width=2pt,dashed] (WCslice\n) to[bend left=10] (WCslice\k);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

AS per your requirement the final arrow is disabled with the line

```
circular final arrow disabled=true,
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions} % library to create annotations 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,quotes,calc,decorations.text,positioning} 

\begin{document} 
\smartdiagramset{
               uniform color list=orange!60!yellow for 5 items,
               circular final arrow disabled=true,
               circular distance=2.25cm,
               arrow tip=to,
               arrow line width=2pt,
additions={
            additional item bottom color=orange!60!yellow,
            additional item border color=gray,
            additional item shadow=drop shadow,
            additional item offset=1cm,
            additional arrow line width=2pt,
            additional arrow tip=to,
            additional arrow color=orange!60!yellow,
            }
}
\smartdiagramadd[circular diagram:clockwise]{
                                             aa,bb,cc,dd,ee
                                            }{above of module1/ADD}
\smartdiagramconnect{to-}{module1/additional-module1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I used your code but when I add two modules to it (i need 7 in total) the figure gets messed up. Also, I don't need that extra module at the top. Please see my revised question text.

Comment: as I said in my previous answer plain tikz is more flexible in this regard with the same amount of coding